# ORA-01652: Unable to extend temp space

Tags: oracle, ora-01652

I have a procedure and a particular query in the procedure is generating about 50GB of temp space causing below exception after few executions.:

SQL state [72000]; error code [1652]; ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP

DBAs are pointing to the below query in the stored procedure that needs to be rewritten. The tables used in the query below are smaller than 0.1 GB but the query generates 50GB of temp space!

```
SELECT tab1.ORDID ID1, tab2.ORDID ID2
FROM (
    SELECT 
    OT.ORDID,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT OT.UNIQ_ORIG_KEY ORIG_UID
    FROM order_tab OT, status_tab ST
    WHERE OT.otype IN ('A','B') 
    AND OT.order_uid IS NULL 
    AND OT.BATCH_ID = ST.BATCH_ID 
    AND ST.CT_DATE = :A1 
    AND ST.BSTATUS = 1 
    CONNECT BY PRIOR OT.UNIQ_KEY = OT.UNIQ_ORIG_KEY 
      ) tab1 , order_tab tab2
WHERE tab2.ORD_VERID = 1 
AND tab1.ORIG_UID = tab2.UNIQ_KEY 
ORDER BY ID1;
```

Could someone please help in rewriting the query efficiently so that temp space utilization is reduced. Database used Oracle 12c.

Comment: Try to remove `ORDER BY ID1` part, and monitor whether something changes. By the way convert your join condition to `) tab1 join order_tab tab2 on tab1.ORIG_UID = tab2.UNIQ_KEY ` and of course remove `AND tab1.ORIG_UID = tab2.UNIQ_KEY ` from Where clause.

Comment: thanks Barbaros. Can we replace connect by clause with something equivalent. may be that's causing the issue

Comment: you're welcome. I don't know if it relieves, and moreover you need that for having a hierarchical type query. But I can advise converting the join `order_tab OT join status_tab ST on OT.BATCH_ID = ST.BATCH_ID` and remove `AND OT.BATCH_ID = ST.BATCH_ID` in the Where Clause for the inner query also.

Comment: thanks,yes that's one thing. I can do that. However, i wasn't sure converting to ANSI can help with execution time.

Comment: I also don't know, needed to be tested in your system.

Comment: I presume ` OT.BATCH_ID = ST.BATCH_ID  AND ST.CT_DATE = :A1  AND ST.BSTATUS = 1 `  should reduce the number of rows being processed to a small number, so perhaps the issue is that these clauses are being applied after the tree-walk, i.e. tree-walk is done first on full table then the join applied. Cannot tell without the explain plan, so I'm just pointing out something to look for. There should ideally be an index on `ST.CT_DATE` and `OT.BATCH_ID`. As a test, what happens if you remove the join and plug in directly the correct value for `OT.BATCH_ID`? If better then dig deeper here.

Comment: Trace your query and post here execution plan. Without execution path, we are unable to guide you to tune the query. I am sure your query is fetching full table scan. Which type of join picked up by SQL engine Hash, Sort merge join, etc. In sql enable tracing.